# Terraform 12 Multiple State Files for each AWS resource on multiple environments

Tags: terraform

Trying to maintain Terraform configuration files in a separate directory path for each AWS resources like Network(VPC, Subnet, NACL, Route Table etc), Security Groups, EC2 Instances(Including ELB and Autoscaling), RDS and Route53. With this setup, Can someone help me with the inputs on how to get the outputs of the subnet Id and the security groups id referenced while creating the instances provided their state files will be maintained in S3 bucket on different folders. Terraform AWS Provider access key, secret key, and S3 back end parameters are passed through Jenkins while doing a plan and apply.

Comment: use one state file every resource is too much, I use one state file for environment

Comment: @c4f4t0r Thanks! and When using one state file for all the resources, Can I still have each resource configurations in separate folders pointing to one state file and can you tell me how the outputs of each resources are referenced?

Comment: if you have a dir env/prod with one file for each resource, you will have an state file dedicated for prod environment

Comment: Current structure is this way, directory "network" contains - vpc, subnet, security groups tf configuration files(tfvars, variables, main, outputs) and another directory named "compute" contains EC2 instances and Route53 tf configuration files(tfvars, variables, main, outputs). Trying to find how I can reference the Subnet and SG Ids outputs while creating the EC2 instances.

Comment: Right now I have only one environment "dev" and all the configurations goes under dev directory however I have segregated as "compute" and "network" as the design demands

Comment: and when you use terraform plan all the resource states will end up in the terraform state file, if you want to apply only on single resource in the dev dir you can -target option in this way, terraform apply -target=aws_instance.hello